# Transiting via Moscow & Havana

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, russia, cuba

I am an Indian Citizen. Will fly from India to Moscow (Sheremetyevo) then to Havana and onward travel.

My Travel itinerary are as follows. From DEL-SVO (5 hrs layoff) then from SVO-HAV (22 Hrs Layoff) on 24th June finally HAV-GCM on 25th June. All are on different tickets.

I want to know, as I have seen in the website of Russia and Cuba, that 24 hrs stay in Russia and 72 Hrs in Cuba respectively does not require any visa. Just want to clarify further if anyone has informations or experiences on this matter?

Comment: I have Indian Passport. My Travel itinerary are as follows. From DEl- SVO (5 hrs layoff) then from SVO - HAV(22 Hrs Layoff) on 24th June finally HAV- GCM on 25th June. All are on different tickets.

Comment: Can you name the airlines for each ticket? It may be helpful to know due to possible interline agreements for checking through your bags.

Comment: 1. From Aeroflot SU233 : Delhi to Moscow.(Layover Time: 6 Hrs)              2. From Aeroflot SU150 : Moscow to Havana. (Layover Time: 15 Hrs)       3. From Cayman Airways KX835  : Havana to Georgetown.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't leave the airport airside, you shouldn't need a visa for Russia. I've had (a few years ago) a 6 hour or so wait at SVO, and didn't need one. you're just a transfer passenger, and are herded from arrival to departure via a special queue (a slow one, took us like 3 hours waiting, there were literally like a thousand people waiting there and only a single desk was open, and after that a single X ray machine and metal detector everyone had to pass through).
That was on a flight from Amsterdam-Moscow-Tashkent btw. and both legs were on the same ticket, so we were checked in for Tashkent from Amsterdam.
 You might have to stand in line some more at another desk to get your boarding pass, there are desks for that inside the terminal at SVO like at any other major airport.

Best you can do if you expect problems is to contact the airlines, airport, or Russian consulate.

Don't know the situation in Cuba, but same applies for there.

Comment: I will be flying from Aeroflot from Delhi to Moscow and again from Moscow tp Havana from Aeroflot both om diffrrent tickets. And next day from Cayman airways on other ticket.